# Converting strings in eps images to mathematical content with Lualatex and pstool

Tags: luatex, eps, psfrag, pstool

I saw a post about this problem, but I can't fix my problem with the suggested solution. Maybe I am doing something wrong or the packages have changed. Can someone help me?
The code is:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifLuaTeX
  \usepackage{polyglossia}
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pstool}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
    \psfrag{A}{$\alpha_{xx}$}
    \includegraphics[]{example-A.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The intention is to use psfrag to change the strings in the eps file to mathematical mode. If needed I am happy to send the image?

Comment: can you add the eps (as a code block)

Comment: simplest would be to process just the image with latex/dvips and classic psfrag to get a pdf with the math in, then include the new pdf into the lualatex

Comment: The code block is to long. Can I Upload the eps picture somehow?

Comment: no, there is no file upload here. could you make an example using `example-image-a.eps` and replace `A` by `$\mathfrak{A}$` or something and check that it shows the problem you are asking about (example-image.eps is available already for tests in the standard tex distributions)

Comment: Yes, it still exists

Comment: OK so you could edit the question to have a reproducible example

Comment: OK, I have updated the example

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifluatex
 \usepackage{fontspec}
\fi 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[crop=pdfcrop]{pstool}
\begin{filecontents}{example-image-a.tex}
\psfrag{A}{$\alpha_{xx}$}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \psfragfig{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Remarks

- the compilation for the psfrag will need `--shell-escape`
- pstool will call `latex + dvips + pspdf` for the picture, not lualatex. In your example it doesn't matter, as you are using only math. You need to take care that your document works with latex too.

  It is currently not possible to use lualatex instead of latex as `dvips` can handle open type fonts (there is  a replacement here https://github.com/vtex-soft/texlive.xdvipsk/, but it currently patches luaotfload files and files from graphics-def and so it not fully compatible with a current texlive. With miktex it probably doesn't work at all.).
- the crop option avoids to load the preview package which is not fully compatible with a current latex, e.g. there are problems with hyperref.
- Read the documentation of pstool regarding the files it needs and the options of the `\psfragfig` command.

[image]